# How to use vi mode in fish shell?

Tags: vim, vi, fish

I saw [vi-mode implementation](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/pull/1218) for fish shell, but I have no clue how to use it. Is there any tutorial available online describing basic functionality, e.g. how to switch modes?

Answer (score 190, accepted):

In fish `2.3.0` and later:

- Run  `fish_vi_key_bindings` to start vi mode
- Run `fish_default_key_bindings` to go back to default mode

If you want to make it the default, add the `fish_vi_key_bindings` command to `~/.config/fish/config.fish`.

Comment: See [this issue](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/2254) for how to setup a different vi esc key. Fish versions after 2.2.0 should let you do this via a `fish_user_key_bindings` function, but in the meantime I used the solution shown by the first post on that issue in my `config.fish`.

Comment: To remove the annoying vi mode indicator (capital i for insert mode), override the fish_mode_prompt function.  `alias -s fish_mode_prompt 'echo'`

Answer (score 12):

I am using fish 2.2.0. The following worked for me:

Edit `$HOME/.config/fish/functions/fish_user_key_bindings.fish`

```
function fish_user_key_bindings
  fish_vi_key_bindings
end
```

via [this](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/1435#issuecomment-123500071)

Comment: @DrNeo How does that relate to `fish` shell?

Comment: Its not related, as far as I know `zsh-vi-mode` is for zsh-shell not fish-shell